# Компьютерная графика, мягкие тени, Nvidia OptiX

Tags: c++, графика, cuda, raytracing

Пытаюсь реализовать мягкие тени, как y [Inigo Quilez](https://iquilezles.org/www/articles/rmshadows/rmshadows.htm) (живой пример на [shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/lsKcDD))

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

только при помощи [Nvidia OptiX](https://developer.nvidia.com/optix), и что-то не очень пока могу разобраться, в какой части конвеера OptiX я могу это запрограммировать.

Реализация во фрагментном шейдере, как у автора, в момент нахождения пересечения запускает новый луч и во время трассировки собирает информацию о тени.

Насколько я смог понять, мне нужно написать еще одну или дополнить оригинальную программу нахождения пересечения с геометрией в сцене и добавить информацию о тени в RayPayload во время итераций rtTrace?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Информации по OptiX в интернете крайне мало, есть официальный [quickstart](https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/optix/optix_quickstart.htm), который я начал ковырять и сразу немного в ступоре.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне представляется, что при честной трассировке лучей и наличии неточечного источника освещения тени и так будут получаться мягкими.

Comment: @VTT все так, но алгоритм который я пытаюсь перенести на optix делает мягкие тени для точечных источников

Comment: @VTT вот пример реализации во фрагментном шейдере https://www.shadertoy.com/view/lsKcDD